# function for loading pages with delay in Kotlin Android has an error

Tags: android, function, kotlin

I am making an APK that needs a lot of loading page often with a little delay. so I decided to create a class named `PageLoaderWithDelay` and I want to have a function in it named `lunchActivity` and I pass arguments as current context, target context and the time I want to wait for loading the page.

When I want to create that class I have a problem and it says that the parameters are not proper .

This is the code of my class:

```
class PageLoaderWithDelay(var context: Context, var targetClass: Class<*>, var delayTime: Long) {
   
    fun lunchActivity() {
        val r =
            Runnable {
                var tmp = Intent(context, targetClass)
                startActivity(tmp)
            }
        val h = Handler()
        h.postDelayed(r, delayTime)
    }
    
}
```

The IDE says that the `startActivity` method needs `Context` but I passed `Intent` but it is not true, since when I use this code not as a function it works properly and with no error.

Actually I think the problem is with type of my arguments (`context` and `targetClass`).

Could you help me find the correct type for them and solve this problem?